# Is there a way to reference an individual cell/row/column in the results of a FILTER function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know I can reference the whole result of a FILTER function with cell reference plus #.
In this case F40#[image]

Is there a way to reference a particular "cell" in the result of a FILTER function?
In this case I want something like F40#(.Cells(2,2))

Comment: `=Index(FILTER(Table4,Table4[qty]>10),2,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`

```
=LET(f,FILTER(Table4,Table4[qty]>10),
INDEX(f,2,2))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, LET pops out in every answer to my question. Time to get familiar with the function!

Comment: yes - it is really one of the best improvements - esp. as it increases readability of formulas massively - when using meaningful names.

Comment: That is what I wasn't able to formulate as a question years ago, after having half-screeners with 5th nested IF and INDEX. Would it be nice to take a part of the formula and name it Chunk A and having the whole formula as =IF(Chunk A=TRUE, ChunkA, ChunkB)